# Cant Load data Mysql and show error "is not alowed to connect host" in VB

Tags: vb.net, class, mariadb, basic

net
i try to create a class for CRUD and i have error
for display data to gridview

this is my class for connection and run query

```
 Imports MySql.Data.MySqlClient
Public Class klass_koneksi
    Public sqlconn As New MySqlConnection
    Public query As String
    Public query_table As String
    Public v_grid As New DataGridView
    Public sqlcmd As New MySqlCommand
    Public sqladpt As New MySqlDataAdapter
    Public sqltabel As New DataTable

    Public Function open_db()
        sqlconn.ConnectionString = "server=127.0.0.1;username=root;pwd=;database=inventor_brg"
        sqlconn.Open()
    End Function

    Public Function Run_Query(query)
        Try
            sqlcmd = sqlconn.CreateCommand
            sqlcmd.CommandText = query
            sqlcmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
        Catch ex As Exception
        End Try
    End Function

    Public Function open_table(query_table, v_grid)
        Try
            sqlcmd.Connection = New MySqlConnection
            sqlcmd.CommandText = query_table
            sqladpt.SelectCommand = sqlcmd
            sqladpt.Fill(sqltabel)
            v_grid = sqltabel
        Catch ex As MySqlException
            MsgBox("cant connect :" & ex.Message)
        End Try
    End Function

    Public Function close_db()
        sqlconn.Close()
        sqlconn.Dispose()
    End Function


End Class
```

and load data code

```
Sub load_data()
    Dim sql_select As New klass_koneksi
    Dim query As String = "Select* from t_barang"
    sql_select.open_db()
    sql_select.open_table(query, Mgrid.DataSource)
    sql_select.close_db()
End Sub
Private Sub frmbrg_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    load_data()
End Sub
```

and this code show error
cant connect:Host'xxxxxxxxxxxxx' is not allowed to connect MariaDB server
is there anything wrong with my class code for load data to grid view?

Comment: I would look directly at the connection string. If you can't connect the problem is there.

Comment: Just as a side note Public fields in a class violate encapsulation. It appears that most can be private. It seems the query variable is only used in the one function and should be local to that function. Drop the class level query variable.